# `UISearchDisplayController` SearchTableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I m using `UISearchDisplayController` in my one of screen of iphone application.my need is to see only a `UISearchDisplayController` as user type in uisearchbar it will load the searchtableview and show data.now my problem is everything is going gud but when i try to select the row of search tabelview my `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate not firing and thus the searchtableview never hides after it untill i click on cancel button of search-bar.and when i try to tap the row of searchtabelview my search bar hides and only serachtableview not hide and nothing can happen on did-select deleget method.

i have done folwing thing .so can anyone please tell me what my mistake is.

> NOTEL:i dont have any other tableview in screen.just uisearchtableview
>   of search display controller(is that causing a problem?)

```
self.searhController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                                            initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar
                                            contentsController:self];
    self.searhController.delegate=self;



    self.searhController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searhController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    [self.searhController setDelegate:self];
    [self.searhController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
    [self.searhController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];

#pragma mark TableView Delegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView== self.searhController.searchResultsTableView) {
        if(self.searchResults.count<=0)
            return 0;
        else
            return self.searchResults.count;
    }
    else{
        return 0;    }



}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if(tableView==self.searhController.searchResultsTableView){


        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
        City *cityObj=[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cityObj.name;
    }

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



    if (tableView==self.searhController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self.searhController setActive:NO animated:YES];


        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
        [self.searhController setActive:NO animated:NO];

    }

}
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

    if ([[searchString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length])
        self.tvSearchView = self.searhController.searchResultsTableView;
    else
        self.tvSearchView = controller.searchResultsTableView;


    if(searchString.length>=3){


        [self getCityList:searchString];

        return YES;

    }
    else{
    return NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: set break point before if loop in didselectRow and try once whether its firing?

Comment: i have tried that its not firing and cellforrowatindex is firing that time.when i scroll tableview but not didselect

Comment: sure you could have been set delegate properly. Where you set breakpoint before if loop right?

Comment: you set delegate using coding or using IBOutlet? and do you have added any gesture to the view

Comment: oops i have set some gesture on uiview for hiding keyboard.. its solved..thanx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58875/discussion-between-yohan-and-bhavik-kama).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you You set some tapGesture to the view so don add gesture to the view at `viewDidLoad()`. Add Gesture to the view when you start typing in the textfield and when you `didFinish` typing remove the gesture from the view. So it won affect tableview from `didslect()` problem